# Where is FrameworkElementFactory in Silverlight5

Tags: silverlight

i have googled for FrameworkElementFactory in Silverlight, don't we have this Class, if not do we have any other alternative please help me.

```
  FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
                spFactory.Name = "myComboFactory";
                spFactory.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, Convert.ToDouble(3));
                spFactory.SetValue(Grid.HeightProperty, Convert.ToDouble(3));
                spFactory.SetValue(Grid.RenderTransformProperty, new TranslateTransform(-6, -6));


                FrameworkElementFactory ec1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Ellipse));
                ec1.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, Brushes.Red);
                spFactory.AppendChild(ec1);
```

Above code is working fine WPF applicaion, but now i want to do the same in Silverlight5
I am using VS 2010, Silverlight5 
i want to add DataTemplate Dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FrameworkElementFactory does not exist in Silverlight. If you want to generate DataTemplates at run time, you must use the XamlReader class.

For you case, you might do something like this:

```
ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
DataTemplate template = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(
    @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
        <Grid Width=""3"" Height=""3"">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X=""6"" Y=""6"" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Ellipse Fill=""Red"" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;

listbox.ItemTemplate = template;
```

Note that you must define the default namespace in the root element (xmlns=...).

---

It is also interesting to note that you can/must use this method to programatically set the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck.

Comment: @Siler Solver:  it's not throwing exception, but no elements are being displayed.. found different solution like Directley Creating Object for Eclipse class and Fill with the Respective color.. Thanks for the effort and valuble time